# How do i get access to Facebooks javascript api in a Kotlin React project?

Tags: facebook, kotlin-js, kotlin-frontend

I have a project using "kotlinFrontend" to create a really nice react front end written in kotlin. How do i get access to the facebook js sdk (it is usually done withing script tags)

I have this code on my HTML template that includes the generated bundle containing

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '503127050093992',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v3.2'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Inside my kotlin react code, how would i then be able to access the creatd FB obj?

Answer (score 0):

Use `external var FB`

Type-safe way:

1. Get typescript definitions from [facebook-js-sdk](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/facebook-js-sdk)
2. Use [ts2kt](https://github.com/Kotlin/ts2kt) to convert it to Kotlin. Generated files might have some errors, but they are usually easy to fix.
3. Add these files to your project. You'll get `external var FB: facebook.FacebookStatic` that you can access.

Unsafe way:

1. Declare `external var FB: dynamic`